# Elasticsearch KNN Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, knn

I am trying to use Elastic's KNN feature to search for image embeddings but am facing issues with it.

Here is my mapping (for this part:

```
"embedding": {
  "properties": {
    "vector": {
      "type": "dense_vector",
      "dims": 128,
      "index": true,
      "similarity": "cosine"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a sample document:

```
{
        "_index": "default_faces",
        "_id": "9ce12fd38e6f4af4b1e3427554fd7d85_1",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "mediaId": "9ce12fd38e6f4af4b1e3427554fd7d85",
          "faceId": 1,
          "location": {
            "x": 2207,
            "y": 488,
            "width": 325,
            "height": 325
          },
          "userLabel": {
            "date": "2023-09-28T20:22:15.798Z",
            "label": "Sara"
          },
          "detectedLabel": {
            "date": "2023-10-03T17:21:52.597409868Z",
            "modelId": "model2023-10-03T17:12:22.925157505Z",
            "confidence": 0,
            "label": "Sara"
          },
          "embedding": {
            "vector": [
              0.12479653,
              -796910910,
              -1.2466574e+26,
              -1.7084357e-9,
              -0.086385354,
              -1.1149039e-36,
              -8.154371e+28,
              -4.254634e-13,
              -0.020866161,
              -23.583464,
              -3.6086323e-7,
              -6.962498e-32,
              0.004263491,
              6.059929e-25,
              -7.281584e-33,
              -2.0290611e-37,
              0.06373995,
              9.384077e+29,
              278131090000000000000,
              7.8216023e-16,
              0.16248108,
              -3115416.2,
              9.196936e-11,
              1.3465332e-31,
              0.13689724,
              -1.03025e-17,
              -0.0003113601,
              -1.1490415e+29,
              0.11705329,
              1.57793e+37,
              5.2369203e-23,
              -5.111619e-22,
              -0.0190556,
              -3.0603685e+34,
              -0.030363373,
              -1.9539207e-23,
              -0.07506746,
              6514624400000,
              -239524640000000000,
              2.0809675e+24,
              0.014151651,
              -6.0877165e-25,
              5.825397e-32,
              1.6479968e+23,
              0.056163397,
              -6.146336e+34,
              6.917795e-15,
              -9.77735e-9,
              0.086990304,
              1.6848381e-13,
              -2.1487435e-27,
              0.00007017374,
              -0.18024889,
              0.023220336,
              6.2720634e+37,
              -9.0323224e-13,
              0.005233554,
              2.6669496e-12,
              -2958941750000,
              8.56959e-26,
              -0.036579296,
              -99135136,
              -109918200000,
              1.3557992e-24,
              -0.009266328,
              3.1252316e+37,
              -5.004035e-29,
              8.4924265e-37,
              0.12848087,
              5.880646e+28,
              -1.8872884e-28,
              0.01775324,
              -0.18414854,
              -8.6509584e-11,
              -6.4468826e+21,
              2.2020109e+27,
              -0.01445858,
              424296143000000000,
              1.254739e-11,
              5.601636e-25,
              0.14763397,
              -5.883017e+28,
              501727968,
              221120528000,
              0.051343855,
              4.1052554e-17,
              -0.040097542,
              1.1383543e-33,
              -0.008345876,
              -4.4398305e+23,
              -1.024667e-13,
              -4.2065526e+29,
              0.117511556,
              -1.0055344e-20,
              6.701807e-20,
              -8.252063e-24,
              -0.074767336,
              -2.8527556e-34,
              -2.4691074e-10,
              -0.0000013078021,
              -0.0887137,
              1.7497632e+21,
              62326103000000,
              -13720.685,
              -0.09684445,
              0.0057914658,
              1.5231384e+34,
              -4.7808005e-32,
              -0.27240166,
              -6865099900000000000,
              -0.00002655319,
              -367.74017,
              -0.09556554,
              -1.11533555e-36,
              8.314042e-28,
              1.7712529e+26,
              0.014347675,
              -5.9712125e+31,
              2148322640000000,
              -1.0245365e+24,
              0.0070601646,
              201760047000,
              6.178222e-37,
              -2.6520108e-26,
              0.07276024,
              1.4955389e-28,
              1.9683766e-18,
              -696073910000
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

And here is the query:

```
{
  "knn": {
    "field": "embedding.vector",
    "query_vector": [
      0.12479653,
      -796910910,
      -1.2466574e+26,
      -1.7084357e-9,
      -0.086385354,
      -1.1149039e-36,
      -8.154371e+28,
      -4.254634e-13,
      -0.020866161,
      -23.583464,
      -3.6086323e-7,
      -6.962498e-32,
      0.004263491,
      6.059929e-25,
      -7.281584e-33,
      -2.0290611e-37,
      0.06373995,
      9.384077e+29,
      278131090000000000000,
      7.8216023e-16,
      0.16248108,
      -3115416.2,
      9.196936e-11,
      1.3465332e-31,
      0.13689724,
      -1.03025e-17,
      -0.0003113601,
      -1.1490415e+29,
      0.11705329,
      1.57793e+37,
      5.2369203e-23,
      -5.111619e-22,
      -0.0190556,
      -3.0603685e+34,
      -0.030363373,
      -1.9539207e-23,
      -0.07506746,
      6514624400000,
      -239524640000000000,
      2.0809675e+24,
      0.014151651,
      -6.0877165e-25,
      5.825397e-32,
      1.6479968e+23,
      0.056163397,
      -6.146336e+34,
      6.917795e-15,
      -9.77735e-9,
      0.086990304,
      1.6848381e-13,
      -2.1487435e-27,
      0.00007017374,
      -0.18024889,
      0.023220336,
      6.2720634e+37,
      -9.0323224e-13,
      0.005233554,
      2.6669496e-12,
      -2958941750000,
      8.56959e-26,
      -0.036579296,
      -99135136,
      -109918200000,
      1.3557992e-24,
      -0.009266328,
      3.1252316e+37,
      -5.004035e-29,
      8.4924265e-37,
      0.12848087,
      5.880646e+28,
      -1.8872884e-28,
      0.01775324,
      -0.18414854,
      -8.6509584e-11,
      -6.4468826e+21,
      2.2020109e+27,
      -0.01445858,
      424296143000000000,
      1.254739e-11,
      5.601636e-25,
      0.14763397,
      -5.883017e+28,
      501727968,
      221120528000,
      0.051343855,
      4.1052554e-17,
      -0.040097542,
      1.1383543e-33,
      -0.008345876,
      -4.4398305e+23,
      -1.024667e-13,
      -4.2065526e+29,
      0.117511556,
      -1.0055344e-20,
      6.701807e-20,
      -8.252063e-24,
      -0.074767336,
      -2.8527556e-34,
      -2.4691074e-10,
      -0.0000013078021,
      -0.0887137,
      1.7497632e+21,
      62326103000000,
      -13720.685,
      -0.09684445,
      0.0057914658,
      1.5231384e+34,
      -4.7808005e-32,
      -0.27240166,
      -6865099900000000000,
      -0.00002655319,
      -367.74017,
      -0.09556554,
      -1.11533555e-36,
      8.314042e-28,
      1.7712529e+26,
      0.014347675,
      -5.9712125e+31,
      2148322640000000,
      -1.0245365e+24,
      0.0070601646,
      201760047000,
      6.178222e-37,
      -2.6520108e-26,
      0.07276024,
      1.4955389e-28,
      1.9683766e-18,
      -696073910000
    ],
    "k": 10,
    "num_candidates": 100
  }
}
```

NOTE: I am using the exact same vector for the query as my sample document.

When I run the query I get an index out of bounds error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/default_faces/_search?error_trace=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_out_of_bounds_exception","reason":"Index 2147480870 out of bounds for length 13","stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException$1: Index 2147480870 out of bounds for length 13
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.guessRootCauses(ElasticsearchException.java:667)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.guessRootCauses(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.guessRootCauses(ElasticsearchException.java:649)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.generateFailureXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:595)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.rest.RestResponse.build(RestResponse.java:176)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.rest.RestResponse.<init>(RestResponse.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.rest.RestResponse.<init>(RestResponse.java:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.rest.action.RestActionListener.onFailure(RestActionListener.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.rest.action.RestCancellableNodeClient$1.onFailure(RestCancellableNodeClient.java:96)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.client.internal.node.NodeClient$SafelyWrappedActionListener.onFailure(NodeClient.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.tasks.TaskManager$1.onFailure(TaskManager.java:217)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations.safeAcceptException(ActionListenerImplementations.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations.safeOnFailure(ActionListenerImplementations.java:72)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.DelegatingActionListener.onFailure(DelegatingActionListener.java:27)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations$RunAfterActionListener.onFailure(ActionListenerImplementations.java:206)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.raisePhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:752)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:729)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:419)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.FetchSearchPhase.moveToNextPhase(FetchSearchPhase.java:273)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.FetchSearchPhase.lambda$innerRun$2(FetchSearchPhase.java:110)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.CountedCollector.countDown(CountedCollector.java:40)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.CountedCollector.onFailure(CountedCollector.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.FetchSearchPhase$2.onFailure(FetchSearchPhase.java:227)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$ConnectionCountingHandler.handleException(SearchTransportService.java:621)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$UnregisterChildTransportResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1702)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1419)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:1555)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:1530)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.transport.TaskTransportChannel.sendResponse(TaskTransportChannel.java:51)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.support.ChannelActionListener.onFailure(ChannelActionListener.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.onFailure(SearchService.java:1139)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable.onFailure(ActionRunnable.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:28)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.TimedRunnable.doRun(TimedRunnable.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:983)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\nCaused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2147480870 out of bounds for length 13
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:385)
    at org.apache.lucene.core@9.7.0/org.apache.lucene.index.CodecReader$1.document(CodecReader.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.search.internal.FieldUsageTrackingDirectoryReader$FieldUsageTrackingLeafReader$2.document(FieldUsageTrackingDirectoryReader.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.index.fieldvisitor.StoredFieldLoader$ReaderStoredFieldLoader.advanceTo(StoredFieldLoader.java:182)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase.prepareNonNestedHitContext(FetchPhase.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase.prepareHitContext(FetchPhase.java:197)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase$1.nextDoc(FetchPhase.java:142)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhaseDocsIterator.iterate(FetchPhaseDocsIterator.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase.buildSearchHits(FetchPhase.java:161)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase.execute(FetchPhase.java:76)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.lambda$executeFetchPhase$8(SearchService.java:810)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable$2.accept(ActionRunnable.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable$2.accept(ActionRunnable.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable$3.doRun(ActionRunnable.java:72)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)
    ... 6 more\n"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"fetch","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"default_faces","node":"waoxWY4iQYKJqsKyhMc49A","reason":{"type":"index_out_of_bounds_exception","reason":"Index 2147480870 out of bounds for length 13","stack_trace":"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2147480870 out of bounds for length 13
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:385)

   [...]

    at FindFaultyDoc.searchForSelf(FindFaultyDoc.java:60)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at FindFaultyDoc.run(FindFaultyDoc.java:45)
    at FindFaultyDoc.main(FindFaultyDoc.java:31)
```

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch is this?

Comment: I could not reproduce this on 8.10.2, it works well. You might want to upgrade

Comment: Yeah, I suspect it is https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/81167 which was fixed in 8.0.0. That's why I asked about the version.

Comment: I'm using version 8.9.0. So this fix should already be in. @Val, the challenge is that if I don't get the error if I reduce the index to one doc and one query. I suspect it might happen when the candidate docs don't have the field or something like that

Comment: @b_habegger that might well be the case, maybe report the issue in the Elastic official Github repo, just to see, what they say?

Comment: @b_habegger yeah, that looks like a bug. Could you try reproducing it with `error_trace` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-error-options) parameter to see where it is coming from? There might be a corresponding stack trace in the logs as well. Without this information elasticsearch team might have difficult time reproducing this issue.

Comment: @imotov I added the stack trace (well part of it to satisfy stack exchange message length) to the description

Comment: Also, for the note, if in the knn I filter for only documents with the embedding field, I do not get any error. So it feels like a missed check somewhere that there indeed is something to compare with.

But now, the weird thing is none of the vectors match anything..

Comment: Ok, it turns out I was wrong. I have a minimal reproducer:

https://gitlab.com/bhabegger/open-media-server/-/blob/d5889285c6d9062889e765c65a02f734dcfcc33c/backend/src/test/scripts/no_knn_results.sh

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely an elasticsearch bug. Repro looks good. Thanks for opening the issue.